# Check a Promo Code from MYSQL Table on Website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a system on my HTML website where you can enter a code which then gets checked by a php-file. 
The php shall compare the code with codes that are in my MYSQL Table. The php shall also check whether the code was allready used or not. 
After the check is completed a message shall appear on the Website that tells the user if his code is valid or not.
If the Code is valid, it shall inform me somehow that somebody entered a code.
I've wrote some code but when I press the button it's not working at all.
Here my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //the min chars for promo-code
    var min_chars = 6;  

    //result texts  
    var checking_html = 'Checking...';  

    //when keyup  
    $('#code').keyup(function(event){ 
        //run the character number check  
        if($('#code').val().length == min_chars){  

            //show the checking_text and run the function to check  
            $('#Promo_code_status').html(checking_html);  
            check_code();  
        }  
    });  

});  

//function to check the promo code  
function check_code(){  

    //get code  
    var code = $('#code').val();  

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("check_code.php", { code: code },  
        function(result){  

        //if the result is 0  
        if(result == 0){  
            //show that the code is correct  
            $('#Promo_code_status').html(code + ' is correct.');  
        }else if(result == 1){  
            //show that the code is correct, but already has been used 
            $('#Promo_code_status').html(code + ' has allready been used.');  
        }else{
            //show that the code is not correct 
            $('#Promo_code_status').html(code + ' is not correct.');  
        }
    });  
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<center><h1>Enter Promo Code</h1>
<form method="post" action="check_code.php">
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code" maxlength="6" />
    <div id="promo_code_status"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Let's go"></center>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here you have my PHP File:

```
<?php

//connect to database  
$user = "***";  //Username
$pass = "***";  //Password
$host = "localhost";  //Host
$dbdb = "***";  //Database name

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
if(!$connect)
{
trigger_error('Error connection to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

//get the code
mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['code']);  

//mysql query to select field code if it's equal to the code that we checked '  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, 'select Code from Codes where Code = "'. $code .'"');  
$record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//if number of rows fields is bigger them 0 that means the code in the database'  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
 if($record['used'] == 0) {
     //and we send 0 to the ajax request  
     echo 0;
} else{
    //and we send 1 to the ajax request  
    echo 1;  
}
}else{  
//else if it's not bigger then 0, then the code is not in the DB'  
//and we send 2 to the ajax request  
echo 2;  
}  
?>
```

By pressing the Button "Let's go" the PHP shall do it's Job and afterwards it shall give the user the information about his code.
What do I have to change?

Comment: Is it giving your any error? If yes, can you post?

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: @M A no I dont get an error

Answer (score 1):

I thing you not assign the post value in $code, that's reason.

```
$code = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['code']);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the jquery CDN that you are using can be accessed. because it looks like wrong CDN.
2. in the `checkcode()` function, you use `#Promo_code_status`, `P` is uppercase, while in html you use `promo_code_status` with `p` is lowercase.
3. in php file you forget to assign values to the `$code`

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your Help, now I get atleast the "Checking.." output, but nothing is happening after that.

Comment: have you changed `#Promo_code_status` in `checkcode()` function ?